# Forcing subclasses of my class to override only certain functions in Java

Tags: java, class, generics, methods, overriding

I have a class, let's say

```
public class GeneralClass<T> {
    methodA() {...}
    methodB() {...}
    methodC() {...}
}
```

and I'm deriving from this class

```
public class MoreSpecificClassString extends GeneralClass<String> {
    methodD() {...}
    methodE() {...}
    methodF() {...}
}

public class MoreSpecificClassInt extends GeneralClass<Integer> {
    methodX() {...}
    methodY() {...}
    methodZ() {...}
}
```

Now, what I would like to know if it is possible to force the subclasses of GeneralClass to override only one method, such as `methodA`?

Thanks

Comment: Force them to override methodA or only allow them to override methodA and not the rest?

Comment: What do you mean "only one function"?  If you want to prevent people overriding `methodB()` and `methodC()`, just declare them `final`.

Comment: I don't find the question very clear. What do you mean by "only one functions"? Can't you declare `methodA` abstract?

Comment: Force them to override only A

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  Make `methodA` abstract and make `GeneralClass` an abstract class.  If you want to prohibit overriding `methodB` and `methodC`, mark them as `final`.

### Edit

If on the other hand you want to be able to provide a default implementation of `methodA`, and *also* require subclasses to override it, you are essentially violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).  You need to reevaluate why you require this design, because it smells pretty bad.  For example, there would be absolutely **nothing** preventing your subclass from just overriding your method like this:

```
@Override
public void methodA() {
    super.methodA();
}
```

And if the re-implementation can just call the super class' default implementation, what was the point in forcing it to be overridden in the first place?

It's for this reason (among others) that it's not possible to provide a default implementation *and* require subclasses to override it.  Rethink your design.

Comment: Values in annotations tagged on a class are tied to each individual class, but only a limited subset of static values can be used. Do annotations that have values (such as @ann(name = "whatever")) violate this principal? If not, what if the value needed to be some other object type that isn't supported in annotations? Or perhaps a dynamic value?

Comment: +1 for pointing out the SOLID violation in your edit. I came across this because I'm working on an OOP solution that runs on top of someone else's code that had already violated the Liskov Substitution Principle. I thought I would mention this scenario where the violation may be unavoidable when creating an OOP bandaid. Maybe not though, I'll have to rethink my bandaid design as well.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, make `GeneralClass` an abstract class, with implementations for the other methods.

Example:

```
abstract class ABC {
  abstract int methodA();
  final int methodB() { ... implementation ...}
}
```

Comment: Right -- you won't have to.  And if you want to prevent subclasses from overriding it, make it `final`.

Comment: By making GeneralClass an abstract class, GeneralClass can't be instanciate... This could be an inconvenient...

Comment: @user: I just addressed this in an edit to my answer.  Your design is really smelly if you need to provide a default implementation but also need to *force* people to override it.

Answer (score 0):

For forcing just a one - make this method `abstract` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have several tools available:

1. You can declare a method (and the base class) `abstract`. Concrete classes will be forced to implement the method.
2. Declare non-overrideable methods `final`. Derived classes cannot override these methods.
3. Combine 1 & 2: declare a method final and have it delegate part of its work to an abstract method. (This pattern is often used with an empty method instead of an abstract method to implement so-called "hooks" into otherwise fixed logic.)